# SQL statement on Mysql for school

Tags: mysql

Looking for better execution and fetch time on this query, would even appreciate suggestion for rewrite. Thanks

```
SELECT *
    FROM job.FilledApplication FA 
     JOIN job.InterviewedCandidatelist ICL ON ICL.FilledApplicationDate =FA.Date      
     JOIN job.SelectedCandidate SC ON ILC.ID = SC.InterviewedCandidateid
Where FA.Date > 12458756236442
ORDER BY FA.Date DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

Comment: instead of SELECT * , better to mention columns

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a condition with just > or < you use range scans (assuming you have an index on the field). Sometimes it helps to limit the range with the largest value in the field so that the optimizer knows better how to execute the scan. For example if you know you have a continuous range you can use this information in your query also by do the following:

```
SELECT *
    FROM job.FilledApplication FA 
     JOIN job.InterviewedCandidatelist ICL ON ICL.FilledApplicationDate =FA.Date      
     JOIN job.SelectedCandidate SC ON ILC.ID = SC.InterviewedCandidateid
Where FA.Date > 12458756236442 AND FA.Date <= (12458756236442+100000)
ORDER BY FA.Date DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

So think about what you know of the data, and apply that.

And always look at the indexes and take care you have appropriate ones (On join conditions, where conditions, optional group by conditions or order by conditions)

Comment: The Query performs better on the Innodb engine than its native ndb engine besides the obvious join issues, i do not see why the query is 10000% faster for the same identical number of rows

Comment: Do you mean the query in my answer, or your query in the two scenarios? If you mean your query, try mine too in both scenarios: The upper limit (however weird it might look) gives a better handle for most query optimizers to be able to give you the better plan. Another way to get the same/similar performance is: Take care histogram information is up to date, and adjust the time the optimizer is allowed to use to determine the query plan (That last one is not really useful for production use, but it can give you the root cause)